# Monitor / listen for Ajax readyState

Tags: javascript, ajax

please see the code below:

```
function createXMLHttpRequestObject() {
    // will store the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
    var ajaxRequest;
    // create the XMLHttpRequest object
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // return the created object or display an error message
    if (!ajaxRequest) alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
    else return ajaxRequest;
}


function ajax_update() {
  var ajaxRequest = createXMLHttpRequestObject();

  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState != 4){ 
    ...
    }

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    //process JSON data
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to monitor/listen for ajaxRequest.readyState value from outside ajax_update() function.
ajax_update() is triggered on button onlick.

MY aim is being outside of function ajax_update() to fire another JS function only when all Ajax calls are completed, that means ajaxRequest.readyState==4.

for ex:

```
 <input type='button' value='SEND QUOTE' onclick=\"ajax_update(some params); function_that_fires_when_readystate_is_completed();\">
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm getting the question. You already use the `readystate` property?

Comment: can't you use jQuery or some other javascript library?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use jquery.

Comment: gdoron: I need to monitor readyState from outside of ajax_update()

Comment: Alexander: for that particular case: yes, only 1 ajax call

Comment: Then move the function call where says `process JSON data`. That's all.

Comment: Alexander: I meant that I have 1 ajax call at a time. I cannot hardcode as you suggested into "process JSON data". I have multiple buttons with different ajax calls and I am using single general ajax function ajax_update()

Answer (score 0):

define this globaly

```
 var requestCounter = 0;
```

and then

```
function ajax_update() {
  var ajaxRequest = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
  //after calling request.open();
    requestCounter++;

  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){  

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState != 4){ 
          requestCounter--;
          //error code here
    }

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        //process JSON data
          requestCounter--;
    }

     if (requestCounter == 0)
          onAllRequestComplete();
  }
}


     function onAllRequestComplete(){
        // code that have to run when all requests have been completed
     }
```

hope that help.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid setTimeout... but instead to use an event listener.

Comment: you mean to listen to readyState using jquery? or rewrite ajax_update function with jquery?

Comment: before answering your question let me ask one first.why you haven't defined your code in onreadystatechange and you defined another function to listen for response to be ready?

Comment: Behnam Esmaili: because ajax_update() is a generic function, and I won't need to listen to readyState everytime I call it.

Comment: then why not calling this generic function when your request have been finished?

Comment: Behnam Esmaili: ok, I have ajax_update <= this is a generic function I am using everywhere. Sometimes I need to know readyState value to fire some other functions, being outside of ajax_update.

Comment: @ihtus u used term "i am using everywhere".ok it means that for every request u must call this function.is it true?if yes then u can call this function each time u receive the response.are you agree with this?

Comment: Behnam Esmaili: yes, to get a ajax response I call ajax_update. "u can call this function each time u receive the response" - u mean call again ajax_update after i got response from ajax_update?

Comment: in fact rather than calling the generic function synchronously u can call Asynchronously and when receiving the response.

Comment: in this code :
 
 if(ajaxRequest.readyState != 4){ 
    ...
    }

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        // Here is where you Recieve the response.
        // process JSON data

        // Call you generic function here.
    }

Comment: when I was saying generic function I meant ajax_update itself. there is no sense to call ajax_update inside ajax_update.

Comment: now i get you pal.but this line was very confusing : onclick=\"ajax_update(some params); function_that_listens_to_readyState**(); i was thinking that you wanna call another function after ajax-update.

Comment: sorry for confusion, i have just edited: function_that_fires_when_readystate_is_completed

Comment: did your problem solves if you make sure all requests have been completed?

Comment: I think yes, I have 1 ajax call per 1 button. There are multiple buttons on page. So, after pressing one button it takes some time to process. I need to fire a function outside of ajax_update (inside onclick) only after the ajax response is received.

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback.

## JS

```
function ajax_update(callback) {
  var ajaxRequest = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      callback();
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open(...);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

## HTML

```
<input onclick="ajax_update(function_that_listens_to_readyState);">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ajaxRequest1.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState != 4){ 
    ...
    }

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    //process JSON data
       firstIsReady  = true;
       check();
    }
  }

ajaxRequest2.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState != 4){ 
    ...
    }

    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    //process JSON data
       secondIsReady  = true;
       check();
    }
  }

function check() {
    if (firstIsReady && secondIsReady) {
        //both ajax calls completed
    }
}
```

Something like that. It's really ugly, but without knowing exactly what you want to do, I can't give you a better way to do it.